# How to compare strings against command prompt input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, comparison, command-prompt

I only started looking into the Ruby language two days ago and have quickly learned that I am far too constrained into the mindset of C derived languages... I am trying to do the comparison on strings as such:

```
def menu_listen
    action = gets
    while !(action.eql?("up")) && !(action.eql?("down")) && !(action.eql?("close")) do
        puts "'#{action}' is not a valid command at this time."
        action = gets
    end
    return action
end
```

...which was earlier written as such:

```
def main_listen
    action = gets
    while action != "up" && action != "down" && action != "close" do
        puts "'#{action}' is not a valid command at this time."
        action = gets
    end
    return action
end
```

I read on this site that thisString.eql?(thatString) is the same as thisString == thatString, it would seem so because neither work. Any input I type into the command prompt does not get past the while loop and gives me this in response:

```
'down
' is not a valid command at this time.
```

So does this mean that the press of the enter key is also stored as a new line on the command prompt input? Can anyone tell me how to implement this so that the string comparison works properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gets` takes in the eol character as well, so use `gets.chomp` to only take in the actual string. The [`chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) method removes your carriage returns as well as your newlines.

As far as the string comparison goes, it's a little more ruby like to just compare whether or not your input exists in an array of predefined strings instead of chaining `&&` and `eql?`, for example:

```
while not %w(up down close).include? action do
```

This is cleaner than the chaining, and makes it easier to modify too.

Answer (score 2):

```
def menu_listen
  until r = (['up', 'down', 'close'] & [t = gets.strip]).first 
    puts "#{t} is not a valid command"
  end
  r
end
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a [String#chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp) method, which removes the separator from the end of the string.

```
    def menu_listen
      while 1 do
        action = gets.chomp
        return action if %w(down up close).include? action.downcase
        puts "#{action}' is not a valid command at this time."
      end
    end
```